How do I use dotenv with import in javascript
I want to use dotenv via node.js
I already tried with "require" but the browser does not support it. On the documentation it is advised to use import with ES6, which I did but there are still errors that I am trying to resolve.
In the index.mjs file I imported dotenv exactly as in the documentation.
import 'dotenv/config'
dotenv.config();

I received an error: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "dotenv/config". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
So I modified the code
import '/dotenv/config'
dotenv.config();

I received another error: GET http://...../dotenv/config 404 (Not Found)
I need help because I can't get the code to work. I installed Node.js at the root of my folder and the ".env" too. Here is my package.json.
{
  "name": "testnode",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "nodeTest",
  "main": "index.mjs",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "airtable": "^0.12.1",
    "browserify": "^17.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2"
  }
}


but the browser, correct browser don't have the concept of environment variables.  You could get environment vars sent to the browser, but this all depends on what your backend build system is etc.

It should be as simple as this, if your packages are installed properly:
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();

I have tried this already, it seems to be working.
import express from "express";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
const app = express();
dotenv.config()

app.listen(process.env.BACKEND_PORT, ()=>{
    console.log(`Server started at ${process.env.BACKEND_PORT}`)    
})

I'm not sure what you mean by "but the browser does not support it", as environment variables are not meant to be accessible directly from the browser to begin with.
